# Windows not detecting a graphics card, yet program on windows can

Tags: graphics-card, motherboard, gpu

I have a Gigabyte GA-Z97X-UD7 with 2 Sapphire Tri-X R9 390 cards and an MSI R9 390X. The MSI and one Sapphire are plugged into PCIEx1-PCIEx16 risers because I'm using them for mining ethereum. On the Device Manager and when I run `wmic path win32_VideoController get name` windows only shows two R9 390s and the built in Intel HD 4600 graphics. Yet when I run the claymore mining program, I start mining on the 390 and the 390x but not the second 390! (as verified by both the logs which recognize the 390x and the heat coming from the cards.) The native Sapphire overclocking tool recognizes both 390s and not the 390x... So the only program that 'sees' the 390x is the miner, but that one doesn't see one of the 390s. Any suggestions on how I can get Windows to recognize the 390x or why the Claymore miner recognizes it but not the 390?

I am running Windows 10.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to isolate the problem to my riser. When I took the 390x out of the riser and installed it directly to the motherboard, windows was able to recognize it normally.